# Парсинг содержимого тега с определенным класом php

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Задача такова - есть виджет с курсом валют. Надо вытащить из него информацию о курсе валюты, использую такой код:

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
    function curl_get($host, $referer = null){
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.51");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        define('CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE', 113);
        define('CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4', 1);
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $html;
        }
  $result = curl_get("https://mconvert.net/get-exchange-rates-widget?base=btc&amount=1&lang=ru&curr=kzt&theme=blue&type=1&font=1&ssl=1");
```

До этого момента все выходит отлично! Но дальше я пробую найти содержимое тега с двумя классами label label-default по регулярному выражению, но что то не так:

```
 $fer = preg_match_all("~<span class=\"label label-default\" style=\"background-color: #d9edf7; color: #2277BD;; font-size: 12px\">\s+(.*?)\s+<\/span>~s",$result, $arr);
    foreach($arr as $v) {
    echo $v[0]."<br>";
    echo $v[1];
    }
```

Но почему то ничего не находит, я где то ошибся в регулярном выражении??

подскажите что не так где ошибка?

Comment: Замените `\s+` на `\s*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка возле "\s+", потому как "+" означает наличие как минимум одного символа, а в исходном тексте нету пробельных символов.

У меня получилось распарсить с помощью более простой регулярки

```
label label-default.*>(.*?)<\/span>
```

Вот смотрите: https://regex101.com/r/xkLIrT/1